# How to add flowfield to RTC report?

Tags: dynamics-nav

how to sum up flow field in Microsoft Dynamic NAV and show it in RTC report ?

thank for your help,
Makara

Answer (score 0):

When you define your report in NAV, then all calculations are done in NAV before the data is transferred to the report viewer. That means you need to make sure that your FlowFields are calculated - using CalcFields(fieldname) - when they are created in NAV. 
So you have to control that the classic report (assuming your question is about NAV 2009, as the term RTC is not used with NAV 2013 anymore, as 2013 only have the "rtc") is printing the calculated field correctly.

Then in the RDLC report designer you can just use the field "as-is". No need to do anything special here.

/Erik